# Convergent Sequence in (R, $d_{2}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I was thinking about the following problem/proof:

In (R, $d_{2}$) let there be a convergent sequence $x_{n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $x$. Prove the following result:

$1/x_{n}$ $\rightarrow$ $1/x$ if $x\neq0$.

I am thinking about this:

If $\epsilon>0$ and we want to show that $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such as  |1/$x_{n}-1/x$|<$\epsilon$ for any $n>\mathbb{N}$.

Knowing that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$, then $\exists$ N such as |$x_{n}-x$|< ???

How can I derive/find the threshold stated in ?. I am stuck in this part and would like to write the complete proof.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $d_2$? Why are you using the [tag:proof-writing] tag?

Comment: $|\frac 1 {x_n}-\frac 1 {x_n}| \leq \frac {|x_n-x|} {|x|(|x|-|x_n-x|)}$

Comment: Hi Jose. I put the proof-writing tag because this is my first post and I did not know what tag to put. Which tag should I use?

Comment: Geetha, can you explain further how you got your threshold? Thank you